# Analog pinouts of the ATTiny85?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, analog, atmel, attiny85

I'm looking to buy a ATTiny85 for a school project. We require 4 analog inputs for our LEDs which we're using as makeshift light sensors (this part of the project is sorted). I've read the the pin layout of the ATTiny85 and it says that there are 4 ADC pins however the ADC0 pin is also the RESET pin and so not sure if that means it can't be used as for analog input.

If this can be used then my second question is whether an ATTiny85 can be sufficient for the use of 4 LEDs and 2 DC motors (which I hope can be connected to the digital pins). Id prefer not to get the larger 14-pin version as we are looking to save space.

Is there any ATTinys that have 10 maybe 12pin layouts also?

Comment: According to the [list](http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/avr/tinyavr.aspx) of all ATTinys, ATTiny13 and ATTiny13A are available in 10 pins package. But, unfortunatly 2 pins of the 10 are DNC. So all in all there isn't any ATTiny with 10 functional pins.

Comment: @BenceKaulics Not ones with exactly 10 functional pins, no. But there are ones with 12 functional pins. Also ones that are teensy with 20 pin packages. Tinier than the 85 and cheaper too. Tn841-MMH for example.

Comment: @Asmyldof the Tn841-MMH can be programmed using arduino though? Not that it's completely necessary but we'd either want to programme using C or arduino

Comment: Any Tiny can be programmed with C. That's how they work. I know nothing of Arduino. In fact, if you want really small and a Tn part, get the 1.5x1.5mm Tiny20 Bump package. Although you will make your fab angry possibly.

Comment: @Asmyldof The benefit we saw with the ATTiny was it can be done in arduino. So it meant we could use my existing arduino and test on that before buying the microcontroller. We don't require to run in arduino, but I'd like to test the code on the arduino as test, and not sure how I can write C code for that.

Comment: If you use generic calls in Atmel Studio (free download) you can program for the Tiny85 and then use the same majority of the code for the Tiny841 or any other later. But I don't know 100% how generic the calls for Tinies are in the latest Studio version.

Comment: I guess external multiplexer before an ADC input are also not an option, regarding space/board size.

Comment: @BenceKaulics Mmm I'd prefer not but if we can get away with it then that would be good. Would complexity be of issue? Below is been stated that the DC motors should be analog rather than direct drive. So if we require 4 light sensors (analog input) and 2 dc motors (analog output) would a multiplexer be too slow compared to just using a bigger controller?

Comment: I would not worry about the speed of the multiplexer, a mux I have recently used for similar purpose, adds typically 29 + 5 + 31ns (tON + tPropagationDelay + tOFF) delay to the system @ Vcc = 5V, less than 1us @ Vcc = 2V and the conversion time of the Tiny85's ADC is around 65-260us. Controlling a 4 channel mux requires 2 digital output, would not be too complex. But a bigger controller could be better, because a MUX and a smaller MCU may occupie more space.

Comment: @BenceKaulics May result in getting the ATTiny84 then. Its 14 pins but the would be more compact circuit design.

Comment: Use the ATtiny24/44/84 in the 14 pin DIP package. 12 GPIO, 8 ADC. None of the ADC overlap the Reset. So you'd have 4 ADC, 6 GPIO, that leaves 1 GPIO free, 2 with reset.

Comment: Please put the DC motor current and voltage requirements into the question.

Comment: @Andyaka We haven't been given the specifications for the motor yet (we get the motor next week) when we get that I'll edit

Comment: @Kristopher  Please do better preliminary research.  To check the existence of a ATtiny with a given specification, go to Atmel web site.  They have selection filters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The ATtiny**

No Atmel do not have 10 or 12 Pin Tinys (with full features)

**The Reset Pin**

Using the reset pin as anything else does carry the risk of you becoming unable to reprogram the MCU without the use of HVPP (High Voltage programming)

A poor-mans 2:1 multiplexer can often just be a pair of FETs, so if you have the room for a few external components then that would solve your problem.

**Driving Components**

As for driving LEDs and motors I will take this opportunity to remind you to make use of suitable drive circuits for these. I would advise against direct drive, especially for the motor (being an inductive load and all).
Below is a suggestion for a motor drive. (Components would depend on your needs.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fviFuS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Space vs Cost**

Saving cost and saving space in electronics are often a compromise, you can get an Atmel MCU in a size that is smaller than a tiny, but you will need a PCB, I would recommend trying a TQFP break board or similar. If you are prepared to move to an SMT package then your space vs function problems will disappear.

If you move to a custom PCB design, you can probably get all of your drive circuitry in SMT packages and squeeze it into a very small space.

A custom board will cost you, although there are cheap sources.

It sounds to me like if space is really that important then you should investigate a solution with SMT parts and a custom PCB.

Comment: Mmm, so although it's a reset pin, I can still technically use it for analog input? Also, can you give an example for the 'drive circuits' not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: You can, but it makes you life harder from a debugging point of view.

Comment: The ATtiny20-MMH has 12 functional pins. But it is nearly impossible to place by hand.

Comment: BGA is not fun to place by hand. QFP, SOIC or SOP is quite easy. And QFP is very space efficient compared to in-line packages.

Comment: _"No Atmel do not have 10 or 12 Pin Tinys (with full features)"_ - There are severay attiny's with 10+ pins, see [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR_ATtiny_comparison_chart).